# Get the last element in HTML structure

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Can I access the last div with the + content only with css & child combinators? I would like to style it.

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <div>
                      +
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

with :last child i can't reach so deep into the tree.

Comment: `div:not(:has(div))`

Comment: tnx it works :)

Comment: @Barmar ... Could you provide an answer in place of a comment please.
I tried to test this but without success. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The selector `div:(not(:has(div))` will match any DIV that doesn't have another DIV nested inside it.

`:has(selector)` matches an element whose contents include an element that matches `selector`. Putting this in `:not()` reverses the condition.

This is a relatively new CSS selector, and it's not yet supported by Firefox as of version 108. See the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility).

```css
div:not(:has(div)) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  a
  <div>
    b
    <div>
      c
      <div>
        d
        <div>
          e
          <div>
            f
            <div>
              g
              <div>
                h
                <div>
                  i
                  <div>
                    j
                    <div>
                      +
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kindness but the "+" symbol is not red but black. @Barmar I would like to understand this css selector.

Comment: It's in red for me.

Comment: Still no Firefox support

Comment: @Kaiido ok, it works on Opera but not on Firefox nor Safari.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a description and a link to the compatibility table.

Comment: @Barmar what is your browser???
Thank you for the edit!

Comment: I'm using Chrome 108.

Comment: I also tried Safari 16.2 and it works.

Comment: On high Sierra I have only Safari 13 @Barmar :(

Comment: This is a VERY new feature, you need a recent browser. If you need to support older browsers, you'll have to code something in JavaScript, you can't do it with CSS.